# Python MySQL update statement with variables

Tags: python, mysql

I'm unable to get MySQL update statement working using variable.  In my case I'm testing with just a simple list that contains couple of strings and I'm trying to execute following:

```
did_test = ['123456789', '123456788', '123456787']

sql_insert = """UPDATE JAX2 
            SET LOCATION = 'NY', ASSIGNEE = 'John Smith', IN_USE = '1' 
            WHERE DID = %s"""
mycursor.execute(sql_insert, did_test[1])
mydb.commit()
```

If I run WHERE condition as such:

```
WHERE DID = '123456788'
```

That works fine with no issue.  I'm just trying to run this with variables because eventually I will be reading in this value from JSON...  I keep getting this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str(123456788), it must be of type list, tuple or dict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `cursor.execute()` needs to be a tuple, so use this version:

```py
mycursor.execute(sql_insert, (did_test[1],))
```

Full script:

```py
did_test = ['123456789', '123456788', '123456787']

sql_insert = """UPDATE JAX2 
            SET LOCATION = 'NY', ASSIGNEE = 'John Smith', IN_USE = '1' 
            WHERE DID = %s"""
mycursor.execute(sql_insert, (did_test[1],))
mydb.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have one single param, it has to be passed as a list or a tuple.

```py
did_test = ['123456789', '123456788', '123456787']

sql_insert = """UPDATE JAX2 
            SET LOCATION = 'NY', ASSIGNEE = 'John Smith', IN_USE = '1' 
            WHERE DID = %s"""
mycursor.execute(sql_insert, [did_test[1]])
mydb.commit()
```